# What is the jTDS driver?

Tags: jdbc

I have heared about the jTDS drivers with JDBC to connect with SQL Server, but I do not know how to use it. Do I need to download the drivers of it? How would I use them?

Comment: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ Theres information, documentation and a download link on there, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You do need to download. Driver, which processes ODBC function calls, submits SQL requests to a specific data source, and returns results to the application and driver manager loads drivers for the application.